# CardView Not Masking Inside Parent

Tags: android, android-cardview

I want to put the `CardView` inside `Rounded LinearLayout`. but I got my layout still square, but If I put the Another view, it is rounded.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false" />
</LinearLayout
```

Here my rounded layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="@color/white" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
</shape>
```

I try use `app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"` but still doesn't work.
How to my card become rounded because it is inside rounded parent?

I have tried another way.

I change the parent using CardView and implementation `app:cardCornerRadius`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false" />
</LinearLayout
```

But still same, `CardView` child covering `CardView` parent

Comment: please share @drawable/rounded

Comment: why don't you use card `CardView_cardCornerRadius`. You have to understand that CardView is subclass of FrameLayout and nesting CardView under LinearLayout is not optimal if you have CardView as its only child.

Comment: i don't understand why are you using rounded LinearLayout when you can do all that stuff with CardView.

Comment: it's just example because of my case my card view inside horizontal ListView, so the item covering rounded parent.

Comment: @V-rund Puro-hit: I have tried using `CardView` on parent, and use `app:cardCornerRadius` it still same

Comment: @Rahul Kumar: I update my post, because still not working

Comment: so basically you want a shadow with stroke ?

Comment: @V-rund Puro-hit: I want the CardView in the child not covering parent.

Answer (score 0):

Give equal radius to `CardView`.

```
<LinearLayout
    ...>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        ... />
</LinearLayout
```

Comment: I update my post, I have try it but still doesn't work

Comment: I did not tell you that.

Answer (score 0):

do something like this ..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
         app:cardCornerRadius="130dp"/>
</LinearLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

you can adjust `app:cardElevation` and `android:padding` as per your need.

cheers.